# Android speech recognition result dialog won't show up

Tags: java, android, android-studio, speech-recognition

I am implementing Speech recognition in android app. But after i speak to my phone, app show me MainActivity (I am starting speech recognition Intent from different activity), and Dialog witch options to choose won,t show up. Below you can find my code.

```
public class AddFoood extends Activity {
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
Button voice;
Dialog match_text_dialog;
ArrayList<String> matches;
ListView textlist;
String SPEACH_RESULT;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_foood);
    getActionBar().setTitle("Add Food");

    voice = (Button)findViewById(R.id.voiceButton);

    voice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isConnected()){
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                //intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                        //RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 15);

                startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public  boolean isConnected()
{
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo net = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (net!=null && net.isAvailable() && net.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        match_text_dialog = new Dialog(AddFoood.this);
        match_text_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_matches_frag);
        match_text_dialog.setTitle("Select Matching Text");
        textlist = (ListView)match_text_dialog.findViewById(R.id.list);
        matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, matches);
        textlist.setAdapter(adapter);
        textlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                SPEACH_RESULT = matches.get(position);
                match_text_dialog.hide();
            }
        });
        match_text_dialog.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify a language with `RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL`

You should use `RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE` instead. Modify your code as follows:

```
//Specify language
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
// Specify language model
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
```